# Why is Flask saying that my table is undefined?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a flask app with Flask-Sql-Alchemy, however flask in't recognising the database table User_Plans I created and trying to query.

It gives the following error:

NameError: name 'User_Plans' is not defined.

I could be wrong, but it feels like the error is a scoping issue.

I have included my code below.

Can you help? Many thanks in advance.

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_user import UserManager, UserMixin, SQLAlchemyAdapter
from datetime import datetime

def create_db(app):

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False, server_default='')
        active=db.Column(db.Boolean(),nullable=False,server_default='0')
        email = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False,unique=True)
        confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
        plan_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plans.id'),default=1)


    db_adapter = SQLAlchemyAdapter(db,User)
    user_manager = UserManager(db_adapter,app)

    class User_Plans(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        user_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        plan_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plans.id'))
        start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    class User_APIs(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        user_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        api_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tools.id'))
        api_key=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True)

    class Tools(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        tool=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True)

    class Plans(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        plan=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True)
        price=db.Column(db.Float(5),nullable=False)
        credit=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)       

    class Usage(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        user_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        task_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
        datetime=db.Column(db.DateTime())

    class Tasks(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        task=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False,unique=True)
        credit=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)

    class Status(db.Model):
        id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        status=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,unique=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

from flask_mail import Mail
from config import config
from database import create_db
from flask_user import login_required, current_user
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def create_app(config_name):
    print(config_name)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    create_db(app)
    mail = Mail(app)


    @app.route('/')
    @login_required
    def index():
        user_id = current_user.id
        start_date=User_Plans.query.with_entities(User_Plans.start_date).filter(User_Plans.user_id==user_id).first()
        return '<h1>Hello {}, you started your plan on {}</h1>'.format(current_user.username,start_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

**manage.py**

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app('development')

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't talking about your table, it's talking about the name `User_Plans`, which is indeed not defined in your main code. You need to import it - and any other models you use - into that file.

```
from models import User_Plans
```